# Function call in the resnet code in python

Tags: python, resnet

There is a function f(input): like the below in resnet file inside another function called _conv_bn_relu. But in this function the "input" passed as an argument to the function f is not available in this function. From where is "input" parameter obtained?

```
def _conv_bn_relu(**conv_params):
    """Helper to build a conv -> BN -> relu block
    """
    filters = conv_params["filters"]
    kernel_size = conv_params["kernel_size"]
    strides = conv_params.setdefault("strides", (1, 1))
    kernel_initializer = conv_params.setdefault("kernel_initializer", "he_normal")
    padding = conv_params.setdefault("padding", "same")
    kernel_regularizer = conv_params.setdefault("kernel_regularizer", l2(1.e-4))

    def f(input):
        conv = Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                      strides=strides, padding=padding,
                      kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                      kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer)(input)
        return _bn_relu(conv)

    return f
```

Comment: The name of the parameter is an internal detail of the function; whoever eventually calls `f()` (by way of the return value of `_conv_bn_relu()` will supply an actual value for that parameter.

Comment: Note that `f` is never called, it's just returned  from `_conv_bn_relu`. You can pass around functions like other values in Python.